# insert in radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I am working with RadGrid.RadGrid fill by SqlDataSource
But when i want Grid to be used only for Inserting new records and RadGrid  data set is empty,the grid is not visible,only a single line appears in the web page
Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement `OnNeedDataSource` event handler

Markup

```
<rad:RadGrid runat="server" ID="mainGrid" 
                 OnNeedDataSource="mainGrid_NeedDataSource">
</rad:RadGrid>
```

Code-Behind

```
protected void mainGrid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    //provide the datasource for your grid
}
```

**Update**

Several things could have caused that - 1) the one in my answer 2) error in your query 3) empty result [without setting ShowHeaderWhenEmpty=true],... [and something more](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid3"  runat="server"    DataSourceID="MySqlDataSource" ......> MySqlDataSource select by parameters

Comment: Several things could have caused that - 1) the one in my answer 2) error in your query 3) empty result [without setting ShowHeaderWhenEmpty=true],... and something more

Comment: yes result is empty  but ShowHeaderWhenEmpty set true when click AddRow single line appears in the web page

Comment: You've not set things up rightly. You might want to show your markup or follow telerik example here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

did you put |Your_data_grid.bind

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.